# data is not transferred between PHP scripts when I use get axios in react

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, axios

there are two php files, on one I create $_SESSION on the other I get the values

**signin.php:**

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');

header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");

header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");

session_start();
    
   
    $_SESSION['id'] ='value1';
      $_SESSION['email'] = 'value1';
     // echo $_SESSION['id'];
      session_write_close();

      $response = [
        'success' => true,
      ];
      
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
    //header('Location: http://project/vendor/check-auth.php')
    ?>
```

**check-auth.php:**

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');

header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");

header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");

session_start();



    if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
      $response = [
        'id' => $_SESSION['id'],
        'email' => $_SESSION['email'],
        
      ];
  } else {
    $response = [
      'id' => 'not value',
      'email' => 'not value'
    ];
  }
      
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
   

    ?>
```

here I always get not value

requests in react:

**1**

```
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(event.target);
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('http://project/vendor/signin.php', data);
      console.log(response.data);
    if (response.data.success){
      
}
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

**2**

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://project/vendor/check-auth.php')
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
       // setUser(response.data.email);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);
```

`echo $_SESSION['id'];` in signin.php outputs value1

also if you use `header('Location: http://project/vendor/check-auth.php ');` then the $_SESSION data is passed to check-auth.php

The session data is saved but when I make an axios request the data is deleted,
I spent a lot of time on the problem, please help

Answer (score 0):

If the back- and frontend is run at two different origins, and you don't proxy you request. You problem could be happening because the frontend don't actually send your credentials with the request.

When you create a session in php, you are giving the frontend a cookie which contains the id of that users session. When you are sending a request to a different origin, that cookie is not automaticly sent with the request.

As seen in the docs, the withCredentials flag is set to false as default.
https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config

You can set that to true like this:

```
axios.get('http://project/vendor/check-auth.php', { withCredentials: true })
```

You can also look at proxying your API request while in development, in case you want to deploy back and frontend to the same origin in the end, read more about that here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

Hope this helps you man :)

Comment: I used { withCredentials: true} for post and get request, as shown in your example, encountered a CORP error, installed header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000 '); , instead of header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); and more errors no, but the session data is still not saved, if you still have any ideas why the session data is not saved, please tell me